# ZF2 equivalent of Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ContextSwitch?

Tags: zend-framework2, context-switch

I cannot find something similar in Zend Framework 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called `ViewStrategy` in ZF2.

The `JsonStrategy` is implemented per default and to create your own `ViewStrategy` see [this article](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/zend-framework-2-step-by-step-create-custom-view-strategy/)